# How to set defaultDate in local time using a UTC value from a hidden field in eonasdan-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am populating a hidden field with a UTC date/time value from a database. I am then using some jQuery and the moment library to convert the UTC date to local time and set the default date of a eonasdan-datetimepicker. I am also using the dp.change event of eonasdan-datetimepicker to convert dates that are picked via the widget back to UTC to bind back to the database via the hidden field. Here is my javascript - this works, but I do not like it.

```
$(".datepicker").each(function (index) {
    var utcDateTime = moment.utc($("#" + $(this).data("utc-target")).val(), "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
    var localDateTime = moment.utc(utcDateTime).local().format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
    $(this).find(">:first-child").val(localDateTime);
}).datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
}).on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $("#" + $(this).data("utc-target")).val(moment.utc(e.date).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="PublishedField">Date/Time Published</label>
<div class="input-group date datepicker" data-utc-target="PublishedUtcField">
    <input name="PublishedField" type="text" id="PublishedField" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="PublishedUtcField" id="PublishedUtcField" value="4/10/2015 5:16:00 PM" />
```

While this works, I'm not a fan of the each loop to set the initial value of the datetimepicker. I feel as though it would be cleaner to set it via the defaultDate property, but I am unable to set that property using an anonymous function. I think a dp.initialize or dp.setup event would be a nice solution, but the library does not support something like that, as far as I can tell. This could also be done using some kind of placeholder functionality, but I cannot find any similar scenarios in the docs or on GitHub.

Anybody know of a better way to do this? Is this kind of scenario supported somehow in a way I'm just not seeing or aware of? Am I missing something obvious?